# Get exit code from a command substitution

Tags: bash, shell

In executing the following line in bash:

```
set -e
p=$(mktemp -t "${1}.$$.XX")
```

`mktemp` fails with this message:

```
+++ mktemp -t cpfs.c.o.5643.XX
mktemp: too few X's in template `cpfs.c.o.5643.XX'
```

How can I have the error on fail include errors during command substitutions? Alternatively, how can I propagate the return code form mktemp back such that `set -e`, or my own code can act on the result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Return code of last command is always kept in `$?`.

do something like:

```
command
ERR=$?
```

To not to lose that return code for later use.

Comment: What about PIPESTATUS? :'(